# When I use gcc with -O1 optimization. Array data initialization is ignored and I end up with uninitialized data when I attempt to use the array

Tags: c, gcc

Using gcc 7.4.0 and compiling this sample program with the -O1 optimization flag, the data being set inside of the array 'cap' is being optimized out leaving me with uninitialized data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CAP_TYPE_1      0x0003
#define CAP_TYPE_2      0x0004
#define CAP_COUNT       2

#define CAP2_CIP_1      0x0001
#define CAP2_CIP_2      0x0002
#define CAP2_CIP_COUNT  2
static uint16_t cap_2_cips[CAP2_CIP_COUNT] = { CAP2_CIP_1, CAP2_CIP_2 };

#define CAP1_ALG_1      0x0010
#define CAP1_ALG_COUNT  1
static uint16_t cap_1_algs[CAP1_ALG_COUNT] =  { CAP1_ALG_1 };

typedef struct optests_cap_1
{
        uint16_t count;
        uint16_t len;
        uint16_t *alg;
        char     *buf;
} optests_cap_1_t;

typedef struct optests_cap_2
{
        uint16_t count;
        uint16_t *cip;
} optests_cap_2_t;

typedef struct optests_cap
{
        uint16_t type;
        uint16_t size;
        uint16_t flag;
        void     *data;
} optests_cap_t;

typedef struct optests_caps
{
        uint32_t count;
        optests_cap_t *structs;
} optests_caps_t;

static int populate_structs(optests_caps_t *caps)
{
        optests_cap_1_t *cap_1;
        optests_cap_2_t *cap_2;

        optests_cap_t cap[CAP_COUNT];

        cap_2 = (optests_cap_2_t*)malloc(sizeof(optests_cap_2_t));
        cap_2->count = CAP2_CIP_COUNT;
        cap_2->cip = cap_2_cips;

        cap[0].type = CAP_TYPE_2;
        cap[0].size = 6;
        cap[0].flag = 0;
        cap[0].data = cap_2;

        cap_1 = (optests_cap_1_t*)malloc(sizeof(optests_cap_1_t));
        cap_1->count = CAP1_ALG_COUNT;
        cap_1->len = 4;
        cap_1->alg = cap_1_algs;
        cap_1->buf = "ABCD";

        cap[1].type = CAP_TYPE_1;
        cap[1].size = 6 + cap_1->len;
        cap[1].flag = 42;
        cap[1].data = cap_1;

        caps->count = CAP_COUNT;
        caps->structs = cap;

        return 0;

}


int main(void)
{
        optests_caps_t caps;
        memset(&caps, 0, sizeof(optests_cap_t));

        populate_structs(&caps);

        printf("cap_count = %u\n", caps.count);
        for(int i = 0; i < caps.count; i++)
        {
                printf("Type: %u\n", caps.structs[i].type);
                printf("Size: %u\n", caps.structs[i].size);
                printf("Flag: %u\n", caps.structs[i].flag);
        }
        /* Free the memory */

}
```

Compile the code with:

```
gcc -O1 -o optest_O1 optest.c
gcc -O0 -o optest_O0 optest.c
gcc -o optest optest.c
```

The output is as such:

```
$ ./optest
cap_count = 2
Type: 4
Size: 6
Flag: 0
Type: 3
Size: 10
Flag: 42
```

```
$ ./optest_O0
cap_count = 2
Type: 4
Size: 6
Flag: 0
Type: 3
Size: 10
Flag: 42
```

```
$ ./optest_O1
cap_count = 2
Type: 2464
Size: 22561
Flag: 32596
Type: 2000
Size: 22624
Flag: 32596
```

Valgrind reports the following when running the optimized binary:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./optest_O1

…

==7316== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
cap_count = 2
==7316== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7316==    at 0x4E9486B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==7316==    by 0x4E97F0D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==7316==    by 0x4F6E2EB: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:35)
==7316==    by 0x10871D: main (in /opttest/optest_O1)
==7316==
==7316== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7316==    at 0x4E94875: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==7316==    by 0x4E97F0D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==7316==    by 0x4F6E2EB: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:35)
==7316==    by 0x10871D: main (in /opttest/optest_O1)
==7316==
==7316== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7316==    at 0x4E98014: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==7316==    by 0x4F6E2EB: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:35)
==7316==    by 0x10871D: main (in /opttest/optest_O1)
==7316==
==7316== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7316==    at 0x4E98B4C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1642)
==7316==    by 0x4F6E2EB: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:35)
==7316==    by 0x10871D: main (in /opttest/optest_O1)
==7316==
Type: 2464

…
```

if I use gcc *-fno-tree-dce -fno-tree-dse* flags along with -O1 I get the correct output. I would like to understand what GCC is doing, is it a gcc bug, or is there a different way to write the above code that would not trigger this issue?

Comment: If you enable all warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror`), [gcc will tell you that this won't work](https://godbolt.org/z/HmxUS8), because `populate_struct` is a static function, so it can inspect it and see what's going on inside.

Comment: Call a few complex functions in between in the -O0 version and you'll see that the memory is corrupted anyway.

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `cap_1 = (optests_cap_1_t*)malloc(sizeof(optests_cap_1_t));`  1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "malloc failed" );` then cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: compiling, with warnings enabled results in: 1) *untitled2.c:70:23: warning: conversion to ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]*  and *untitled2.c:90:26: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]*   These are significant problems that you need to correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gcc is fine, your code is buggy.

```
static int populate_structs(optests_caps_t *caps)
{
        // ...
        optests_cap_t cap[CAP_COUNT];
        // ...
        caps->structs = cap;
}
```

`cap` is local to the function `populate_structs`, so after that function returns, any further access to the memory pointed to by `caps->structs` is undefined behavior.

Maybe you wanted to declare `cap` as static, or use `malloc` to allocate some memory for it.

Comment: Thanks, I allocated memory for it using malloc and then freed it at the end when I was done. Things look great now. I just kept over looking that point. I figured I was doing something silly, as the overall code wasn't that complicated.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this line:

```
caps->structs = cap;
```

This makes `caps->structs` point to the (first element of the) ***local*** array `cap`.

Once the function ends the life-time of this array will also end, and the pointer become invalid. Any dereferencing of this pointer after that point will lead to *undefined behavior*.